# Android: InvalidKeySpecException: encoded key spec not recognised

Tags: android, rsa, spongycastle

When I try to make RSA public key from string. I get exception mentioned below. I am trying to verify generated keys (string, using Swift) in Android. How to convert the string to private/public key?

```
static PublicKey getRSAPublicKeyFromString (String publicKeyPEM){
    try {
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "SC");
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = Base64.decode(publicKeyPEM.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
        X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Exception

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: encoded key spec not recognised
at org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.BaseKeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(BaseKeyFactorySpi.java:52)
at org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(KeyFactorySpi.java:130)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:172)
```

public key in ios:

```
MIGJAoGBAOibWF15OhLJQAWpQN++UFqyG+2uLEG8PPvCajwwh6FWi6jLiZ9VN+l3JpiJTQwF/yxlSJCZCoYnljKeRBnNxpzBnuTJsyuZ4hI8ehLzDvh9nYzX/TlcZYVshJzyIVRZAbuFOCLNIltjB+Qmw8YGlxzeDSFaB6eEC1OP49hDakURAgMBAAE=
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately what you have is a base64 encoded [PKCS#1 RSAPublicKey](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A.1), which is something Java does not produce or consume. Java produces and consumes a slightly more generic and slightly more complicated [X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1).

Using the [Bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) library, here is some example code to produce an RSAPublicKey:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive;

import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String pubkey64 = "MIGJAoGBAOibWF15OhLJQAWpQN++UFqyG+2uLEG8PPvCajwwh6FWi6jLiZ9VN+l3JpiJTQwF/yxlSJCZCoYnljKeRBnNxpzBnuTJsyuZ4hI8ehLzDvh9nYzX/TlcZYVshJzyIVRZAbuFOCLNIltjB+Qmw8YGlxzeDSFaB6eEC1OP49hDakURAgMBAAE=";
        PublicKey rsaPub = readRSAPublicKey(pubkey64);
        System.out.println(rsaPub);
    }

    private static PublicKey readRSAPublicKey(String pubkey64) throws Exception {
        byte [] derRsaPubBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(pubkey64);
        ASN1Primitive asn1Prime = new ASN1InputStream(derRsaPubBytes).readObject();
        org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey rsaPub = org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey.getInstance(asn1Prime);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return kf.generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(rsaPub.getModulus(), rsaPub.getPublicExponent()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not fluent in this issue. Can you give me an idea to fix my air?

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you please show me how to generate public/private key with pkcs#1?